what is wrong with my code: javascript onclick image change image
I'd like to change my image onClick but have the new image get larger with transform
Another thing I'd like to do is I'd like to hide other divs simultaneously when I click this one


function changeImage() {
  var image = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  if (image.src.match("dot")) {
    image.src = "";
    else {
      image.src = "";
    }
  }
}

function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDIV").style.Transform = "scale(2)";
}
<div id="myDIV" onclick="changeImage()"><img src=""></div>




Please do not just paste some unformatted code in the question and expect us to fix it. You were missing a } and had a mess of > > in the code too. I made you a snippet. Also please look up your methods like match to see how they work. In your case even if the match worked, it would change the empty source to empty source regardless

You have added the else tag inside the if tag without providing another if for that else tag. For example use one of the two options below which suits your need.
Option 1:
function changeImage() {
  var image = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  if (image.src.match("dot")) {
    image.src = "";
  }
  else {
    image.src = "";
  }
}

Option 2:
function changeImage() {
  var image = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  if (image.src.match("dot")) {
    image.src = "";
    if(image.src.match("dotcom")){
      image.src = "";
    }
    else {
      image.src = "";
    }
  }
}

Hope it helps...!
